# How to use each table row with different background color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

How I use each table row with different background color like nth-child (even) and nth-child (odd), at first it works as I want, but then when I show only uncompleted tasks it doesn't work

[image: Image from Gyazo]

also when I complete a task where only incomplete tasks are shown this is not updated

I am also trying to avoid rendering all tasks, I tried many things but nothing works and I already run out of ideas

Tasks Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react'
import TaskItem from "./TaskItem";

function saveLocalStorage(tasks) {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
}

function TasksReducer(taskItems, { type, task }) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'UPDATE_TAKS': {
            let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems].map((task) => ({ ...task }))
            let newItems = taskItemsCopy.map((t) => {
                if (t.id === task.id) {
                    t.done = !t.done
                };
                return t;
            })
            saveLocalStorage(newItems)
            return newItems
        }

        case 'ADD_TASK': {
            const newItems = [...taskItems, task]
            saveLocalStorage(newItems)
            return newItems
        }

        default:
            window.alert('INVALID ACTION')
            break;
    }
}

const initialState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')) || []

//STYLES

const styleTable = {
    'borderCollapse': 'collapse',
    'margin': '25px 0',
    'fontSize': '0.9em',
    'fontFamily': 'sans-serif',
    'minWidth': '400px',
    'boxShadow': '0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)'
}

const styleTr = {
    'backgroundColor': '#009879',
    'color': '#ffffff',
    'textAlign': 'left'
}

const styleTh = {
    padding: '12px 15px'
}

function Tasks({ newTask, show }) {
    const [taskItems, dispatch] = useReducer(TasksReducer, initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!newTask) return
        newTaskHandler({ id: taskItems.length + 1, ...newTask })
    }, [newTask])

    const newTaskHandler = (task) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TASK', task })
    }

    const toggleDoneTask = (task) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_TAKS', task })
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>learning react </h1>
            <table style={styleTable}>
                <thead>
                    <tr style={styleTr}>
                        <th style={styleTh}>Title</th>
                        <th style={styleTh}>Description</th>
                        <th style={styleTh}>Done</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                    taskItems.map((task, i) => {
                            return <TaskItem
                                        tasks={taskItems}
                                        index={i}
                                        task={task}
                                        key={task.id}
                                        show={show}
                                        toggleDoneTask={() => toggleDoneTask(task)}>
                                    </TaskItem>
                                
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}


export default Tasks
```

Task Item component:

```
import React, { createRef, memo } from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import store from "../../redux/store";


//STYLES

const DIV = styled.div`

    max-height: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0px" : "50px"
    };

    opacity: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0": "1"
    };

    padding: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0px":"12px 15px"
    };

    overflow: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, max-height 0.5s, padding 0.5s;
`;

/* 
    avoid re-rendering all tasks when changing show state
    that's why it's made this way
    ============================================
*/
const TR = styled.tr`
    background-color: ${
        (props) => {
            //show completed and not completed tasks
            if(useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show)){
                return props.index % 2 === 0 ? '#f3f3f3': 'none'
            }

            //show only not completed tasks ( FIX IT )

            const tasksNotDone = props.tasks.filter((task) => !task.done)
            const index = tasksNotDone.findIndex(t => t.id === props.task.id)
            console.log(tasksNotDone)
            console.log(index)

            return index % 2 === 0 ? '#f3f3f3': 'none'


        }
    };

    /* &:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
    &:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF} */
/* 
    avoid re-rendering all tasks when changing show state
    that's why it's made this way
    ============================================
*/
    border-bottom: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.task.done ? "none": "1px solid #dddddd"
    };;

    transition: visibility 0.5s;

    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #009879;
    }
`;


function TaskRow({ task, toggleDoneTask, index, tasks }) {

    return (
        
        <TR task={task} tasks={tasks} index={index}>
            <td>
                <DIV done={task.done}>
                    {console.log('render', task)}
                    {task.title}
                </DIV>
            </td>
            <td>
                <DIV done={task.done}>
                    {task.description}
                </DIV>
            </td>
            <td>
                <DIV  done={task.done}>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                        checked={task.done}
                        onChange={toggleDoneTask}
                        style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    />
                </DIV>
            </td>
        </TR>

    )

}


export default memo(TaskRow, (prev, next) => {

    //COMPARE TASK OBJECT
    const prevTaskKeys = Object.keys(prev.task);
    const nextTaskKeys = Object.keys(next.task);

    const sameLength = prevTaskKeys.length === nextTaskKeys.length;
    const sameEntries = prevTaskKeys.every(key => {
        return nextTaskKeys.includes(key) && prev.task[key] === next.task[key];
    });
    // store.getState().toggleDoneTasks.show
    return sameLength && sameEntries;
})
```

If you need the complete code

[image: Edit quizzical-franklin-3r93h]

Comment: You could try not rendering the rows if they shouldn't be displayed

Comment: You can move the toggle done method to the parent `Tasks` component and only `map()` the tasks that are visible.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you could try not rendering the tasks that are already `done` when they should be hidden. For example in your map callback you could try doing something like this:

```
{taskItems.map((task, i) => ((show || !task.done) &&
    <TaskItem
        tasks={taskItems}
        index={i}
        task={task}
        key={task.id}
        show={show}
        toggleDoneTask={() => toggleDoneTask(task)} 
    />
)}
```

The logic here: `(show || !task.done) && <TaskItem />` is basically saying, "If we want to `show` all tasks OR the current `task` is not `done`, show the `TaskItem`".

This also requires cleaning up your complex styled components to use CSS instead of calculating the `nth-child` based on index via JS.

Can be done using `&:nth-child(odd)` (or similar).

In addition, you are using a combination of native react's `useState` and react-redux `useSelector` for your `show` prop/state value. I would recommend using `react-redux` as that seems to be what you are using in most of your code. To do that change your `Tasks` component to use `useSelector`, e.g.

```
function Tasks({ newTask }) {
  const show = useSelector((state) => state.toggleDoneTasks.show);
  ...
```

I forked your code with a minimal working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-pascal-vjst8?file=/src/components/Tasks/TaskItem.jsx may need some more tweaks. Hope it helps.

Comment: Now it works better, but I still have no idea how to fix the css problem

Comment: The previous CSS you had commented out `&:nth-child(odd)` should suffice. 

I also noticed that your using a mix of redux and native react `useState` for your `show` variable/state. This is causing some issues with the rendering logic I suggested, I would recommend using one or the other and make sure that when it changes your `Tasks` component gets re-rendered (as it should).

Comment: The CSS that was commented does not solve it

Comment: I updated my fork of your code, it seems to be working now. I had to use `useSelector` in your `Tasks` component for `show` and then it all seems to function now.

Comment: It works fine as I want, but animations or transitions are affected, is there no way to fix that?